# How to share externally Excel file stored in app's internal storage

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to share the .xlsx file stored in App's internal storage.

when i tried below code it shows unable to load reasource.

```
 public void share(String fileName, Context context) 
{
    Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(Environment.getDataDirectory() + getPackageName() + "/files/" + fileName);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
    shareIntent.setType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Send to"));
}
```

any help will be appreciable

Comment: `Storage path is InternalStorage/Android/Data/packagename/files/excel.xslx`. That is not a path you could use as a programmer. Please try to tell us the exact path as this path does not exist. Use a File Explorer app that tells you the real path.

Comment: `Uri.parse(Environment.getDataDirectory() + getPackageName() + "/files/" + fileName);`. Before you try to parse this File object/path to an Uri you could first check with File.exists() is the file really exists.

Comment: @greenapps  path is      /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/(package name)/files/(filename)

Comment: when i hardcode that path..i could send..but is there anyway to get that path programmatically

Comment: Yes that is getExternalFilesDir(null). But still you should check the existence of a file before you try to share that file.

Comment: My god... getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();

Comment: Thank you...and sorry disturbed enough with silly questions